# How do I set environment variables in Code Cells in Scientific Mode?

Tags: python, pycharm, numba

Pycharm is not reflecting the environment variable I set in a code cell. The following code runs in Pycharm (hitting play on the entire script):

```
#%% <- Scientific Mode: on

import os
from pathlib import Path

CACHE_DIR = Path("/home/me/numba_cache")
CACHE_DIR.touch(exist_ok=True)
os.environ["NUMBA_CACHE_DIR"] = str(CACHE_DIR)

from numba import jit


@jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def square(x):
    return x ** 2

print(square(5))
```

However when I run the code cell, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
           ^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 11, in <module>
  File "/home/me/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/envs/my_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/decorators.py", line 234, in wrapper
    disp.enable_caching()
  File "/home/me/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/envs/my_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 863, in enable_caching
    self._cache = FunctionCache(self.py_func)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/me/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/envs/my_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/caching.py", line 601, in __init__
    self._impl = self._impl_class(py_func)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/me/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/envs/my_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/caching.py", line 337, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("cannot cache function %r: no locator available "
RuntimeError: cannot cache function 'square': no locator available for file '<input>'
```

How do I get this to work? I've tried setting the env var in the run configuration, however that only works when the script is run, not an individual code cell

Comment: Use %env magic command to set the environment variable
`%env NUMBA_CACHE_DIR=$CACHE_DIR`

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a Jupyter notebook

Comment: Do you get the same error when you specify `/tmp` as the `CACHE_DIR`?

Comment: Same error ken.